# Python parsing file into dictionary of list of lists: for loop is only appending last line

Tags: python, for-loop, append, fileparsing

I am trying to parse through a file with consistent formatting: a header and several lines of text split by spacing.
I want to start a new dictionary key when a line has one value, read the following lines into a list of lists with each list being the split words.
I first tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473770/processing-lines-of-text-file-between-two-marker-lines) to try to get the program to identify the new marker and use an index counter to set a new key.
I then initially used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922214/reading-a-text-file-and-splitting-it-into-single-words-in-python/16922328) to split the lines accordingly.

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
import sys

def openfile(file):
    frames = {}
    index = 0
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == '5310':
                index +=1
            else:
                newline = line
                print newline
                frames[index] = []
                frames[index].append([newline.split()])
        print frames

openfile(sys.argv[1])
```

The index will correctly count and 'print newline' is printing all of the lines that I want, but the dictionary that is finally printed is a nested list:

```
{1:[['last', 'line', 'of', 'input', 'file']]}
```

What I want instead is:

```
{1:[[line1],[line2] ...], 2:[[nextline], [nextline] ...], ... , key n : [[line], [line]....[lastline]]}
```

I have also tried:

```
def openfile(file):
    frames = {}
    index = 0
    with open(file) as f:
         for line in f:
            if str(line.strip()) == '5310':
                index += 1
            else:
                frames[index] = []
                frames[index].append([line.split()])
    return frames
```

This will also not work.
This leaves me with two questions:
1: why will my current code print but not append the lines I want?
2. what else can I try to get this to work?

*edit* 
Thanks! I managed to get it to work.
If someone is having a similar issue, here's my code that works:

```
import sys

def openfile(file):
    frames = {}
    index = 0
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == '5310':
                index +=1
                frames[index] = []
            else:
                newline = line
                print newline
                frames[index].append([newline.split()])
        print frames

openfile(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: I think you might want to look at [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). `frames[index] = []` wipes all values stored against that key. Without setting up a test case for this, I would use `frames = defaultdict(list)` and get rid of `frames[index] = []` from the loop. Does that work?

Comment: `frames[index].append([newline.split()])` makes `frames[index]` into a list of lists of lists. Use `extend` or remove the extra `[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is obvious ... once you see the problem  :-)

```
            frames[index] = []
            frames[index].append([newline.split()])
```

Every time through the loop, you wipe out the earlier progress, and start with a new, empty list.  Thus, only the last iteration's result is in `frames`.

Initialization code has to be done only once, before you enter the loop.

```
with open(file) as f:
     frames[index] = []
     for line in f:
```

... or other appropriate point for your application.